# How to fetch cover image (album art) of songs in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am making an music app where user can select the songs from internal storage of device with the help of file_picker package and I want to fetch meta data including cover image of music files or songs and display it into the music tile in the UI.
I don't find any package that can fetch the cover image of music files or songs.

Comment: did u solve this?

Comment: No brother.Help please

Comment: you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/dart_tags

Comment: @MarcQuebrarTan Could you please share the example of it? I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

-- Use

**On_audio_query Package** to select all songs -
to get all songs use

```
    getAllSongs = await _audioQuery.querySongs();
```

-- Use
**QueryArtworkWidget**

```
QueryArtworkWidget(
                            quality: 100,

                             artworkBorder: BorderRadius.circular(8),

                             artworkClipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            artworkFit: BoxFit.cover,
                            nullArtworkWidget: Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/assetImage.png'),

                            id: int.parse(myaudio.metas.id!),
                            type: ArtworkType.),
```